# Perform some backend functionality when browser tab is closed

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I want to perform some function in the background when the browser tab is closed.

I am using vuejs and laravel 6.2. it is a laravel mix project.

when the browser tab is closed or removed I want to go in laravel controller and perform methods in the database.

I used the javascript `onbeforeunload` method but it is not working. give me some idea or hint on how to do that.

Comment: You cannot reliably perform work when a browser tab (or the whole browser) closes.

Comment: Thanks God that nobody made this in my browser yet :))

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with a websocket presence channels combined to a publishing. Redis handles a publishing/subscribing mechanism which allows you to react on real-time and trigger some Laravel code.

You need:

- Laravel Echo client which connects to a presence channel ( https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server#presence-channels )
- a Laravel Echo Server which publishes channel content to Redis
- a Redis Server
- an Artisan command which subscribes to Redis and retrieves channel's content => some Laravel code (care, it must be a stand-alone process because PHP is not asynchronous!)

The mechanism is automatically triggered on joining but also on leaving and often the leaving means "tab closed"

Comment: I am using WebSocket and pusherJS for realtime data transfer but I don't know how to apply that in closing tab